# Is multicollinearity ever an issue in ensemble learning?

Tags: multicollinearity, ensemble-learning

Suppose I have two models, A and B, and suppose B takes the output of A as one of its features. Now suppose that both models use at least some of the same features. Is there a potential multicollinearity issue? Or is this too general a question and it depends on the model?

For example, in *Practical Statistics for Data Scientists* by Bruce, Bruce, and Gedeck (2020) p. 247, the authors use the example of KNN output as a feature input to another model, and say that multicollinearity will not be a problem even if both models have similar features because "the information [from the KNN model] is highly local, derived only from a few nearby records, and is therefore additional information and not redundant." In other words, not a problem because of what is unique about KNN. So that is a specific example of ensemble learning with similar features across models not leading to a multicollinearity issue, but I wonder whether the same can be said for ensemble learning in general.

I should also add that we are interested in the variable importance results from B; I recognize that if all we cared about were predictions, then we would not be concerned about multicollinearity in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in general this is a concern. Maybe the best way to see it is with an extreme example:

Consider the case where both models are just linear regression, with the same features. The base model fits, say, $\hat{y}=\beta_0+\mathbf{\beta} \mathbf{x}$.  Then the second model has a continuum of best fits:
$$ \alpha \hat{y} + (1-\alpha)(\beta_0+ \mathbf{\beta} \mathbf{x}).$$

My viewpoint is extremely biased, but I'm not sure I've seen stacking used in an inference problem; it's mostly used in pure prediction contexts.